# Insert using Where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having problem with inserting data with `where` clause. Here is the query:

```
    $hi= "INSERT INTO user_detail (email, looking, username, profession, experience,
         current_work, state, job_type, about, college, diploma, department)
             VALUES ('$email', '$looking', '$username', '$profession','$experience',
     '$current_work', '$state', '$job_type', '$about', '$college', '$diploma', '$department')
 WHERE s='$username'";
```

It shows me the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE s='aniket276'' at line 1

Comment: Why would you use a WHERE during a INSERT ? if your line is already present use an UPDATA instead.

Comment: will update work? what will query would look like @Nirnae

Comment: The syntax of insert query is `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)` Don't use where clause in it

Comment: Are you trying to INSERT a new row into the table, or to UPDATE already existing row(s)?

Answer (score 3):

use MySQL update

like that:-

```
UPDATE user_detail SET email='$email' WHERE s='$username';
```

> You should rather use UPDATE, if you want to change the value of the
>   field in records you select using the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` clause inside insert doesn't make any sens.

If you want to add a new row into your database, you won't need the `WHERE` clause since there is no existing row on which you can refer.

If you want to update an existing row, then you shouldn't use `INSERT` statement but the `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

An insert does not have a WHERE clause.

If you want to only insert a row for a particular username then probably best to do this in your calling php script.

If you want to amend an existing row for a particular username then you would use an update statement:-

```
UPDATE user_detail
SET email = '$email', 
    looking = '$looking', 
    username = '$username', 
    profession = '$profession', 
    experience = '$experience', 
    current_work = '$current_work', 
    state = '$state', 
    job_type = '$job_type', 
    about = '$about', 
    college = '$college', 
    diploma = '$diploma', 
    department = '$department'
WHERE s = '$username'
```

If you want to insert a row if one doesn't exist but update it if it does exist then you can do an INSERT / ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (assuming that the *s* column for the username has a unique index on it):-

```
INSERT INTO user_detail (s,
                        email, 
                        looking, 
                        username, 
                        profession, 
                        experience, 
                        current_work, 
                        state, 
                        job_type, 
                        about, 
                        college, 
                        diploma, 
                        department) 
VALUES ('$username',
        '$email', 
        '$looking', 
        '$username', 
        '$profession', 
        '$experience', 
        '$current_work', 
        '$state', 
        '$job_type', 
        '$about', 
        '$college', 
        '$diploma', 
        '$department') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email = VALUES(email), 
                        looking = VALUES(looking), 
                        username = VALUES(username), 
                        profession = VALUES(profession), 
                        experience = VALUES(experience), 
                        current_work = VALUES(current_work), 
                        state = VALUES(state), 
                        job_type = VALUES(job_type), 
                        about = VALUES(about), 
                        college = VALUES(college), 
                        diploma = VALUES(diploma), 
                        department = VALUES(department)
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert a new record , you dont use WHERE. you WHERE when you want to reference to a specific record. To do that you Use MySQL Update.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp